# How can I declare an interface, function, and variable with the same name?

Tags: node.js, typescript

How can I declare an interface, function, and variable with the same name?

E.g. I want to use the function like:

```
declare function someName(...args: any[]);

someName('foo');
```

The interface:

```
interface someName {
    (...args: any[]): someName
}

function test(arg: someName): someName {
}
```

And use it as a variable (for NodeJS) which should get output as is in the compiled JS.

```
var someName = require('someName');
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you declare the interface, which describes a function, you can also declare a variable with the same name, using the interface as the type:

```
interface someName {
    (...args: any[]): someName;
}

declare var someName: someName;

someName('foo');

function test(arg: someName): someName {
    return this;
}
```

The call to `someName('foo')` correctly guesses what you mean (i.e. the variable `someName`, which is a function).

I implemented the body of the `test` function, as you had it returning a `someName` - just to ensure there are no compiler errors.

The full implementation as a type definition for an external module would be:

*someName.ts*

```
interface someName {
    (...args: any[]): someName;
}

declare var someName: someName;

export = someName;
```

*app.ts*

```
import * as someName from 'someName'

someName('grr', 'arr', 'arg')
```

Comment: I tried this but I get an error trying to compile `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'someName'.`: https://gist.github.com/Petah/96cb895bec02867ad111

Comment: Change the file name from `some-name.ts` to `someName.ts` - the name used in the import statement should be the file name.

Answer (score 2):

Steve answered the question you asked. But I suspect you are looking for the following:

## A Type definition `someName.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'someName' {
    interface someName {
       (...args: any[]): someName
    }
    var someName:someName;
    export = someName;
}
```

## Then use it `app.ts`:

```
import someName = require('someName');
```

## More

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: Seems to work like this, is it possible to get it working with namespaces? https://gist.github.com/Petah/9ed93de155908ba0b496

Comment: @Petah yes.... but don't mix namespaces / modules. Just use modules everywhere. The file automatically doesn't have a global scope if you use modules